# PHP site editor

Tags: php, testing, editor

One question, can someone give a website for test PHP code?
I'm looking for some as http://fiddle.jshell.net/ but for PHP.

Someone can help me?
Thanks ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here, some page maybe usefull for you.

http://writecodeonline.com/php/ 
http://phptester.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one you can try :

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/